# Angular2 Having the value displayed different to the one in the ngModal

Tags: angular

I am wondering if there is a way to have the value displayed different to the one in the ngModel in an `input`. By instance, I want to display a `+` at the beginning of an `input`, even though I don't want it in my `ngModal`.

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="foo" (ngModelChange)="foo = $event.replace('+','')">
```

This obviously doesn't do the full trick as what I see won't have the plus anymore.

I did add in a `setTimeout()` after the `(ngModelChange)` something which is gonna change the value of the input, but that's very hacky and I am pretty sure this is a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Did you consider using a custom pipe?

Comment: I am not sure to see what you want to achieve with a pipe here...